# xls files not getting generate using sql bcp commad

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, com, bcp, clsid

i am getting below error while generate xls file from sql bcp command

"Retrieving the C0OM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000401a." but i have tried multiple solution posted on stackoverflow. still getting same issue its working propelry earlier i got this issue suddenly without any changes in my application.
please help me on this i stuck.

thanks in advance

i tried multiple solution posted on stackoverflow.

Comment: Issue got resovled after some changes in DCOM config, microsoft excel application properties and identity teb  just set the interactive user insteadof this user.